# What is the difference between wget --mirror and --recursive?

Tags: wget

My question pertains to `wget`, a command line tool used for downloading entire websites off the internet. I am having a confusion between the two options `--mirror` and `--recursive`. Are these two options synonyms, in other words, do they do the same thing? Is there a difference between these two options? Which option is used for downloading an entire website? Can we use both these options `--mirror --recursive` together in the same `wget` command, and if so, what happens then?

Comment: “Are these two options synonyms”- No; [They](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html) do different things

Comment: @Ramhound So which one should I use to download a full website, starting from the root directory? And if I use both these options at once, what happens?

Comment: Per @Ramhound link, mirror us a superset of recursive - "‘--mirror’

    Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings. It is currently equivalent to ‘-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing’. "

Comment: @Galaxy - You only need --mirror if you want an infinite recursion depth.

Comment: @Ramhound So in other words, download all the contents of that website?